# Getting GameObject Component

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using this to find some script inside a GameObject:

```
GameObject.Find("GameView").GetComponent<SomeClass>();
```

I'm new to Unity and wanted to see if the following is possible:

```
SomeClass View1;
SomeClass View2;
View2 = GameObject.Find("GameView").GetComponent<View1.GetType()>();
```

Of course that throws an error. But is it possible to dynamically assign the class definition for `GetComponent`?

Comment: @Pluto no it wouldn't. `public bool TryGetComponent(Type type, out Component component);` would. A generic type parameter always has to be compile time constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes and no

not using the generic version but instead [`GetComponent(Type)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html)

```
var view2 = GameObject.Find("GameView").GetComponent(View1.GetType);
```

you get at least the reference as `Component` but the problem is that you most probably still would need to cast it to something more useful in order to execute any methods or access fields on it.

Except `Component` of course is fine for your usecase.

Otherwise if you already know your components will share a certain base class or interface you could use that instead.